# If statement with PDO SQL query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Could someone please assist / advise on how I could use if statements inside a sql query?
I am trying to create a search form where the query would only consider the "category" and the "type" fields if they are not empty?

I have tried the code below, but are receiving an error:

```
    public static function findBySearch($data)
    {
        $location = $data['location'];
        $category = $data['category'];
        $type = $data['type'];
           
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts
            WHERE location = :location';

            if ($category != '') {
            $sql .= ', category = :category';
            }

            if ($type != '') {
                $sql .= ', type = :type';
                }
       
            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           
            if ($category !='') {       
                $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }

            if ($type !='') {       
                $stmt->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                } 

            return $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'

Message: 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' category = 'To Rent', type = 'House'' at line 2'

Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\findingproperty\App\Models\Post.php(269): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\findingproperty\App\Controllers\Posts.php(106): App\Models\Post::findBySearch(Array)
#2 [internal function]: App\Controllers\Posts->searchAction()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\findingproperty\Core\Controller.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\findingproperty\Core\Router.php(121): Core\Controller->__call('search', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\findingproperty\public\index.php(63): Core\Router->dispatch('posts/search')
#6 {main}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You lack logical operators. Multiple conditions aren't chained by commas, but by operators `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you for your reply. Could you perhaps please advise on what would be the correct way to add the logic operators (I have tried adding an AND operator before the if statement, but are receiving a syntax error: "unexpected AND")?

Comment: Stop and think for a moment. What if your PHP `if` condition isn't met and you end up with only one SQL condition? You will have a dangling `AND` at the end of your query. You should only add it if your PHP condition is met - that is, inside it.

Comment: @El_Vanja, thank you very much. I have update the if statements as per below it is now working well. Thank you for your help - much appreciated.

Comment: if ($category != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :category';
            }

            if ($type != '') {
                $sql .= ' AND type = :type';
                }

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

In a `WHERE` statement you have to concatinate conditions with `AND` or `OR` as already pointed out in the comments.

What about this:

```php
public static function findBySearch($data)
    {
        $location = $data['location'];
        $category = $data['category'];
        $type = $data['type'];
           
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts
            WHERE location = :location';

            if ($category != '') {
                $sql .= 'AND category = :category';
            }

            if ($type != '') {
                $sql .= 'AND type = :type';
            }
       
            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           
            if ($category !='') {       
                $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }

            if ($type !='') {       
                $stmt->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                } 

            return $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Or you can do:

```php
public static function findBySearch($data)
    {
        $location = $data['location'];
        $category = $data['category'];
        $type = $data['type'];
           
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
            $where = [
                [ 'column' => 'location', 'value' => $location ]
            ];

            if ($category != '') {
                $where[] = [ 'column' => 'category', 'value' => $category ];
            }

            if ($type != '') {
                $where[] = [ 'column' => 'type', 'value' => $type ];
            }
            
            if (count($where) {
                $sql .= ' WHERE '.join(' AND ', array_map(function($item) {
                    return $item['column'].' = :'.$item['value'];
                }));                
            }
       
            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            
            if (count($where) {
                foreach($where as $column => $value) {
                    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$column, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }

            return $stmt->execute();
        }
```